# Вывести слово, в котором число определенных символов максимально

Tags: java, массивы

Из масива String нужно вывести слово, в котором поторяется максимальное количество раз какая-то буква.
Например, дается

```java
String [] words ={"black","one","doodle","snack","divine"};
String let = "d";
```

Программа должна вывести слово `doodle`

Мой код:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String let = "d";

    String[] words = {"black", "one", "doodle", "snack", "divine"};

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (words[i].contains(let)) {
            System.out.println(words[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Могу вывести слова, в которых встречается буква, но как вывести слово с максимальным повторением буквы?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245490/check-how-many-times-string-contains-character-g-in-eligible-string - есть несколько интересных ответов, как искать кол-во повторений.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ещё одно решение в лоб:

```
char let = 'd';
String[] words = {"black", "one", "doodle", "snack", "divine"};

int max = 0, indexOfMax = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  int wordLength = words[i].length();
  int counter = 0;
  for (int leti = 0; leti < wordLength; ++leti){
    if(words[i].charAt(leti) == let){
      ++counter;
    }
  }
  if(counter>max){
    max = counter;
    indexOfMax = i;
  }
}
```

и решение на `Java 8`

```
long max = 0;
int indexOfMax = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  long counter = words[i].chars().filter(ch -> ch == let).count();
  if(counter>max){
    max = counter;
    indexOfMax = i;
  }
}
```

Для вывода используется:

```
if(max==0){
  System.out.println("Not present");
} else {
  System.out.println(words[indexOfMax]);
}
```

Comment: а почему мы переменной max присваиваем -1 ? почему не нуль, от этого что-то поменяется ?

Comment: А это верное замечание кстати, так она будет работать правильнее xD

Comment: и indexOfMax = -1; тоже не обязательно приисваивать к -1 как я понимаю. Можно в принципе любое значение ?

Comment: Вот тут лучше -1, если укажите то значение, которое существует в массиве может быть ситуация, когда долго будете отлаживать почему выдаёт неправильное значение, а так вылетит с ошибкой

Answer (score 4):

Как то так

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String let = "d";
    String[] words = {
        "black", "one", "doodle", "snack", "divine"
    };
    int maxLetter = count(words[0], let);
    String wordWithMaxLetters = null;
    for (int i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
        //если количество букв в текущем слова больше, чем в максимальном слове, 
        //то запоминаем текущеее слово
        if (count(words[i], let) > maxLetter) {
            wordWithMaxLetters = words[i];
            maxLetter = count(wordWithMaxLetters, let);
        }
    }
    //если не найдено слово с буквой, то выводим not found
    if (wordWithMaxLetters == null) {
        System.out.println("No found");
    } else {
        // иначе выводим слово
        System.out.println(wordWithMaxLetters);
    }
 }
  //заменяем все буквы, которые не letter, на пустую строчку
 static int count(String word, String letter) {
    return word.replaceAll("[^" + letter + "]", "").length();
 }
```

Comment: @https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177093/andrew-bystrov не знаю почему, но код выдает no found почему-то

Comment: @OlegKhegay поправил ответ. Ошибся чутка в регулярке

Answer (score 0):

Ищем максимум по количеству определенных символов в строке:

```java
String[] words = {"black", "one", "doodle", "snack", "divine"};
char letter = 'd';
String word = Arrays.stream(words)
        .max(Comparator.comparing(w ->
                (int) w.codePoints().filter(i -> i == letter).count()))
        .get();

System.out.println(word); // doodle
```